# How to set working directory using python script in ABAQUS?

Tags: python, abaqus

I can't find any python command related to set working directory in python reference guide in ABAQUS.

Is there any way to set working directory using python script in ABAQUS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to how you usually do in `Python`. 
Because, Abaqus Scripting API support `os` module, simply you can use:

```
import os
setPath = r'C:\'
os.chdir(setPath)
```